# What is a recursive function for this program I coded for adding all the digits of a five digit number

Tags: c

I'm not able to code a recursive function for this, I have given the example after the program,

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int sum(int x);
 int main()
{
   int n,s;
   printf("enter the five digit number whose digits need to be added");
   scanf("%d",&n);

   s= sum(n);

   printf("The sum of all the digits of a five digit number is %d",s);

}

int sum(int x)
{

  int d=0,a;

  for(i=1;i>=5;i++)
{
  a=x%10;
  x=x/10;
  d= d+a;  

}
  return(d);
}
```

The following is the recursive code for the above program that I coded myself,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int sum(int x);
int main()
 {

   int n,s;
   printf("enter the five digit number whose digits need to be added\n");
   scanf("%d",&n);

   s= sum(n);

   printf("The sum of all the digits of a five digit number %d",s);

}//This is my poor try inspired by coderedoc
```

//please fix this code my laptop battery gonna be over already

```
   int sum(int x)
  {
   int d=0, a;
   if(x<0)
   return sum(-x);
   else
   a= x%10;
   x= x/10;
   d=d+a;
   return sum(x);
   else
   if(x==0)
   return d;

   }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int sum(int x){
  if( x < 0) return sum(-x);
  return (x==0)?0:(x%10)+sum(x/10);
}
```

The code will be as simple as this. If you reach the `x=0` state you are done. Else add the last digit with the sum of the rest of the digits.

Also when building your solution - try to make it generalize to some extent. `5` digit is good but think if you can extend it for more numbers of digits. This works for that too.

```
int sum(int x){
   if(x < 0) return sum(-x);
   if(x == 0)
       return 0;
   else
       return (x%10)+sum(x/10);
}
```

Comment: whats the role of sum(-x)

Comment: @Matthew.: If negative number I am passing the absolute value of it - so the modulous can be taken and here the sign doesn;t matter - we want the sum of the digits. thats why.

Comment: sum(-x) will return the absolute value of your input.Say input is -10 then this will make the input +10.

Comment: I would really be very happy if you used the if and else style recursive function instead of the conditional operators.

Comment: @Matthew.: I am sure a smart individual like you can convert it to if-else..if you can't let me know...but try first.

Comment: @coderedoc you remind me of my teacher, well ok,
P.S. I mentioned that "I coded the code myself" because the community here really pins you down if you aint done nothing by yourself at all

Comment: @Matthew.: Declare `int d = 0` in the function. And then wrap everything you wrote after `else` in curly braces..`{...}` you will be good to go.

Comment: Edit the code to its correct state and i accept the answet

Comment: @Matthew.: This is the correct code. You can run it.

Comment: @Matthew - Words of wisdom (1) "Never look a gift horse in the mouth."; and (2) "Don't bite the hand that feeds you ."